# How to get InputStream from class which is in nested jar?

Tags: java, classpath

I am working with Spring boot jar and I have got nested jars in my structure.
I am trying to read the raw bytes from the class file. I would like to get InputStream from following URL

"jar:file:/D:/work/dev/target/first.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/second.jar!/a/b/c/Data.class"

I have tried

```
InputStream i = new URL( str ).openStream();
```

But this does not work ( FileNotFoundException ).
I do not want to use spring-boot's API. Since that URL looks pretty standard I am hoping that there should be a way to achieve this.

Comment: at runtime from where you try to load the ressource ? You give the impression to want to access it externally to the spring boot jar.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wanted to achieve this from within the first.jar. That is runtime. I also happened to have access to above mentioned URL. As it stands, getResourceAsStream does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "second.jar" in the classpath?

If yes, use the `Classloader.getResourceAsStream()`

For example:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("a/b/c/Data.class")
```